# How to create dynamic rowspan in table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie in laravel, i'm trying to show the table like image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l52Vo.jpg

```
@foreach($report_data as $index => $item)
<tbody class="table-content">
    <tr>

        <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;">{{ $item->customer_fullName }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->customer_phone }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->customer_detail_licensePlate }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->vehicle_brand_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->vehicle_model_name }}</td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
@endforeach
```

but the output is like image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSktI.png

Thanks!!

Comment: you nead create tabale and header go out of loop

Comment: the \@foreach has to go one line below, and the \@endforeach one line up.  you just have to iterate over the <tr>, not the <tbody>

Comment: I appologies im just edit my image @JoeGalind

Comment: @Mahdi Anjam sorry im just edit image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it as so:

In the controller, select the customers eager loading the vehicles.

```
$customers = Customer::with('vehicles')->get();
return view('customers')->with('customers', $customers);
```

In the view:

```
<table>
    @foreach($customers as $index => $customer)
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="$customer->vehicles->count()">
               {{ $index+1 }}
            </td>
            <td rowspan="$customer->vehicles->count()">
               {{ $customer->fullName }}
            </td>
            <td rowspan="$customer->vehicles->count()">
               {{ $customer->phone }}
            </td>
            <td> {{$customer->vehicles[0]->licensePlate }} </td>
            <td> {{$customer->vehicles[0]->brandName }} </td>
            <td> {{$customer->vehicles[0]->modelName }} </td>
        </tr>
        @for($i=1;$i<$customer->vehicles->count())
        <tr>
            <td> {{$customer->vehicles[$i]->licensePlate }} </td>
            <td> {{$customer->vehicles[$i]->brandName }} </td>
            <td> {{$customer->vehicles[$i]->modelName }} </td>
        </tr>
        @endfor
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not to iterate tbody everytime, just iterate `<tr></tr>` as below

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>License Number</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Brand Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-content">
        @foreach($report_data as $index => $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="text-align:left;">{{ $item->customer_fullName }}</td> //rowspan should be in some condition
            <td>{{ $item->customer_phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->customer_detail_licensePlate }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->vehicle_brand_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->vehicle_model_name }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table">
 <thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">Customer</th>
    <th scope="col">Licence Number</th>
    <th scope="col">Brand</th>
    <th scope="col">Brand Type</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  @foreach($report_data as $index => $item)
  <tbody class="table-content">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;">{{ $item->customer_fullName }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->customer_phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->customer_detail_licensePlate }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->vehicle_brand_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->vehicle_model_name }}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

use this CDN for Bootstrap style

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```